# Rails 4: Assert strings in ActiveRecord/fixture with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, minitest

I am trying out Rails 4 - first steps :) I have two models with fixtures and a HABTM relationship between them with a matching table `authors_books`. All setup and running fine.

Now I want to test for the existence of a string (author names). I am using Minitest.

author model:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
```

the test:

```
test "fixture book has authors" do
    book = books(:book_one)
    # check for correct count
    assert_equal 2, book.authors.count

    # test for existence of "John" and "Mary" inside book.authors
    ...
  end
```

When I use `throw book.authors.inspect`, it shows the expected result from the association in `the authors_books` table:

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Author id: 455823999, name: "John Doe", created_at: "2016-03-01 15:07:32", updated_at: "2016-03-01 15:07:32">, #<Author id: 814571245, name: "Mary Jane", created_at: "2016-03-01 15:07:32", updated_at: "2016-03-01 15:07:32">]>
```

I tried using `assert_match` and some other asserts, but none seems to be able to test inside the *(correct me if I'm wrong with the naming please)* Active Record or Collection. I tried to use `to_s` but failed.

How to test if my strings are inside `book.authors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you've given above try:

```
author_array = ['John Doe', 'Mary Jane']
book.authors.each do |author|
  assert_equal true,  author_array.include?(author.name)
end
```

This will loop through each author in authors and check if author.name is inside the author_array

```
authors_names = ''
book.authors.each{ |author| authors_names + author.name + " "} 
assert_equal "John Doe Mary Jane", authors_names.chomp
```

That'll give you a string separating each name with a space and removing the trailing space. It still requires you to iterate through both authors objects though.

Comment: Thank you. That will do but is somehow a bit much as I think :) Is there no way to make a string out of the result of `book.authors`?

Comment: What is returned to you is basically an array containing two author objects, so some form of iteration is needed, you can do this I suppose:

Comment: The cleanest solution is to use delegation.Then you can just call book.authors_name. This involves some refactoring at the model though, here's a link if you're interested [http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/delegating-all-of-the-things-with-ruby-forwardable/]